# How to remove children from parent entity record in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have `Product` entity and `ProductRating` entity, each `Product` can have many `ProductRating`s. When `Product` is deleted I want to have associated ratings deleted too, but nothing works so far (also `orphanRemoval` set to `true`)...

Classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Min(value = 0)
    private Float cost;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",
            orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<ProductRating> productRatings;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_RATING")
public class ProductRating extends Rating {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @NotNull(message = "Rating must be in context of Product")
    private Product product;
}
```

After `Product` deletion ratings stay with deleted `Product`'s ID

AbstractEntity implementation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity<I> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1700166770839683115L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private I id;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@OneToMany` relation you need to add the cascade type delete: `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}`

Or if you don't mind having all cascade types you can just put: `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

**EDIT:**

Also check the name of the `Product` primary key in the database. 
It should match the defined in the `@JoinColumn` annotation of `ProductRating`

The default database field for the attribute `id` of the `Product` class would be `product_id`. 
However you have defined the id in AbstractEntity as `name = "ID"` so the @JoinColumn should be something like: `@JoinColumn(name = "ID")`

Comment: There is no `CascadeType.DELETE`, did you mean `CascadeType.REMOVE`?

Comment: Yes it is `CascadeType.REMOVE`. But if you want to cascade also when persisting the entity better use `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: _Those two parameters don't work._ That is actually needed for what you need, what there must be something else we are missing. ¿How have you declared your Product Id field in AbstractEntity?

Comment: Please check that the `@JoinColumn` name matches the product id field in the database

Comment: Yes, it matches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202657/discussion-between-pepevalbe-and-janlan).

Answer (score 0):

My alternative approach to fix this problem is to:

- On parent-side relation create method with `@PreRemove` annotation
- in this method iterate over collection with `@[One/Many]ToMany` annotation and call `delete(obj)` method for corresponding repository on child
- On child-side relation create method with `@PreRemove` annotation
- In this method set parent to `null`